# Heroku Toolbelt - Installed, yet Heroku Command not working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've installed the Heroku Toolbelt, yet "heroku" commands (like heroku version) aren't working.

Do you have any idea about what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin` (or whatever else directory where is it installed) to your PATH.